# Select all combinations

Tags: mysql

It’s pretty difficult to explain what I try to accomplish with just word. So I tried to make an example which reflects my real project. I have a group of people (Peter, Aaron, Mark, Alicia, Cleo and Mike) who play games (A, B and C) against each other. What I would like to do with my query is to get all combination who played against each other for the particular games.
So for example:

1. Peter played one A game vs Aaron  he won in 3 rounds - >    Peter -   Aaron  - A  - 1 -  5 -  1
2. Mike played two C games vs Cleo  and lost twice, in 3 and 4 rounds -> 
   Mike  -   Cleo -    C  - 0 -   3.5 -  2

Example table games:

```
id   playRound   player   game   win   rounds 

1    1           Peter    A      1     5
2    1           Aaron    A      0     5
3    1           Alicia   B      0     3 
4    1           Mark     B      1     3
5    1           Mike     C      0     4
6    1           Cleo     C      1     4
7    2           Alicia   A      1     5
8    2           Mark     A      0     5
9    2           Peter    B      1     3
10   2           Mark     B      0     3
11   2           Mike     C      0     3
12   2           Cleo     C      1     3
13   3           Alicia   A      0     4
14   3           Mark     A      1     4
15   3           Peter    B      0     4
16   3           Aaron    B      1     4
17   3           Alicia   C      1     5
18   3           Cleo     C      0     5
```

End result:

```
playerONE   playerTwo   game   avgWinRateOne   avgRounds   Number

Peter       Aaron       A      1               5           1
Peter       Aaron       B      1               3           1
Peter       Mark        B      0               4           1
Alicia      Mark        A      0.5             4.5         2
Alicia      Mark        B      0               3           1
Alicia      Cleo        C      1               5           1
Mike        Cleo        C      0               3.5         2
```

I'm fiddling with this but I Have no idea what im doing

```
SELECT *
FROM (

SELECT *
FROM `testtable`
WHERE `game` = 'A'
GROUP BY `gameId` , `game` , `player`
)tmp1, (

SELECT *
FROM `testtable`
WHERE `game` = 'A'
GROUP BY `gameId` , `game` , `player`
)tmp2
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think maybe you want this query:

```
select p1.player, p2.player, p1.game, avg(p1.win), avg(p1.rounds), count(*)
  from games p1
    inner join games p2
      on p1.playround = p2.playround
        and p1.game = p2.game
        and p1.player != p2.player
  group by p1.player, p2.player, p1.game;
```

It's a relatively basic `join`, where we associate the games table with itself, to get our game pairings, we can them `group by` those pairings, in order to use aggregate functions to calculate the averages, and number of games played.

Running it on your sample data gives this output:

```
mysql> select p1.player, p2.player, p1.game, avg(p1.win), avg(p1.rounds), count(*)
    ->   from games p1
    ->     inner join games p2
    ->       on p1.playround = p2.playround
    ->         and p1.game = p2.game
    ->         and p1.player != p2.player
    ->   group by p1.player, p2.player, p1.game;
+--------+--------+------+-------------+----------------+----------+
| player | player | game | avg(p1.win) | avg(p1.rounds) | count(*) |
+--------+--------+------+-------------+----------------+----------+
| Aaron  | Peter  | A    |      0.0000 |         5.0000 |        1 |
| Aaron  | Peter  | B    |      1.0000 |         4.0000 |        1 |
| Alicia | Cleo   | C    |      1.0000 |         5.0000 |        1 |
| Alicia | Mark   | A    |      0.5000 |         4.5000 |        2 |
| Alicia | Mark   | B    |      0.0000 |         3.0000 |        1 |
| Cleo   | Alicia | C    |      0.0000 |         5.0000 |        1 |
| Cleo   | Mike   | C    |      1.0000 |         3.5000 |        2 |
| Mark   | Alicia | A    |      0.5000 |         4.5000 |        2 |
| Mark   | Alicia | B    |      1.0000 |         3.0000 |        1 |
| Mark   | Peter  | B    |      0.0000 |         3.0000 |        1 |
| Mike   | Cleo   | C    |      0.0000 |         3.5000 |        2 |
| Peter  | Aaron  | A    |      1.0000 |         5.0000 |        1 |
| Peter  | Aaron  | B    |      0.0000 |         4.0000 |        1 |
| Peter  | Mark   | B    |      1.0000 |         3.0000 |        1 |
+--------+--------+------+-------------+----------------+----------+
14 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: Why are there 14 rows when the sample data only lists 9 pairings?

Comment: There are seven distinct pairings (player 1 + player 2 + game), however since there was no instruction how to determine who is player one, this query outputs both combinations for each pairing, doubling the number of results

Comment: Thank you very much is working great. @ xqbert in my example I just save a combination once just Peter <-> Aaron not Aaron <-> Peter. Is it possible to store the combination once? With the win rate linked to player 1

Comment: @PHPhil It is - but how do you decide who is player 1, and who is player 2? ie, why show 'arron v. peter' instead of 'peter v. arron' ?